# RegExp to find first letter of words before @

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm trying to capitalize the first letter of names in an email address. For example, `john.doe@example.com` would become `John.Doe@example.com`. I have some regex that will find the first letter of all the words, but it includes the results after the `@`.

```
/(\b[a-z])/g
```

Is there a way to get just the results before the `@`? I'm doing this in ActionScript but it's pretty standard.

If I have to, I can just use `split('@')` to break the email address up into an array of 2 elements, perform the change on the first element, then put them back together into a single `string` again. I'd rather just use regex to simplify it if I can.

Comment: A good way is to split the email on `@` then use your regex on the first half, then join the two parts back together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided ActionScript's implementation of regex supports look-ahead statements (which, from what I can tell, it should), you can just use a positive look-ahead, like this:

```
/\b[a-z](?=.*@)/g
```

In other words, text will only be considered a match if it is immediately followed by `.*@`.  However, the `.*@` portion is not captured as part of the match.

Comment: Brilliant. That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use a regex that will check if `@` is somewhere ahead from the current match - `/\b[a-z](?=[^@]*@)/g`. The character class `[^@]` matches any character other than a `@`.

Here is a demo code:

```
var str1:String = "john.doe@gmail.com";
var pattern:RegExp = /\b[a-z](?=[^@]*@)/g;
var str2:String = str1.replace(pattern, replFN);
trace (str2);

function replFN():String {
  return arguments[0].toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: I guess `[^@]` validates up to the first `@` where as `.*` validates starting from the last. Either way it doesn't validate a single `@`. Either way, _brilliant_... +1

Comment: To clarify, the difference between `.` and `[^@]` is that `[^@]` includes new-line characters whereas `.` does not.